# fast way find to files in millions of files

Tags: linux, file, find

I had a huge amount of data, about `50*50*10000` files with total file size `3TB`. The file structure looks like:

`/myhdd/Experiment_{id}/Run_{id}/Filename`

Now given a filename, I want to locate where it is; however a straightforward `find /myhdd -name "filename"` is super inefficient. It need to look up the entire harddisk to find one file. Is there a better way to do this, like somehow build an index of my file structure to accelerate `find`?

Comment: That’s 25 million, not billions. Make a Perl hash, or a simple list and `grep` in it so you don’t have to read all the inodes.

Comment: Yes, if you dump all filenames into a file (find . > filenames.txt) then you'll have a no more than 1 GiB text file where you can `grep` for names. May also sort it and then use `sgrep` on it (have to rearrange the fields to have the Filename in front). Or compress the unsorted version and search in it with `zgrep`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `locate` command, it usually works faster than find:

`locate -b filename`

Answer (score 0):

If `locate` or various `find` calls are still slow for your case, you can create and use for searching a file with the paths, as already commented.

You create that "index" file with

```
find . -type f > myindex
```

And you can update it periodically either using `-ctime` to append new files, or from the beginning, it has just the time cost of your search now.

Then you can find the path searching for any filename. This is probably fast enough:

```
fname="myfilename"; awk -F/ -v f="$fname" '$NF==f' myindex
```

[Here](http://superuser.com/questions/341232/faster-alternatives-to-find-and-locate) some more information related to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through similar situations, and can completely understand your pain.
What helped me was `fzf` and `fd` tools.
I also agree with the other answers of creating a local index database which can be put in as a cron job. And you could cook up a SHELL alias to search the index database.
I would let you decide the best option in your case... do get back to us on the efficacy of these methods though :).

Options:

- `fzf`
- `fd`
- Cron Job to create a Index Databse (to update periodically) and a search function within the Index Database.

You could learn more about `fzf` and `fd` from here:

- https://mike.place/2017/fzf-fd/
- https://github.com/sharkdp/fd
- https://github.com/junegunn/fzf

[image]